# extract header info from a get request on a remote URL in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, http, httpwebrequest, http-headers, httpwebresponse

I want to perform a get request on a remote URL and then extract the headers returned.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

As [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.headers.aspx)

If you make any request, `POST` or `GET` like:

```
// Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL. 
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

You will be getting always a `Response` object like:

```
// Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for response.
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

And you can get all the headers with:

```
myHttpWebResponse.Headers
```

And iterate through them like:

```
for(int i=0; i < myHttpWebResponse.Headers.Count; ++i)  
    Console.WriteLine("\nHeader Name:{0}, Value:1}",myHttpWebResponse.Headers.Keys[i],myHttpWebResponse.Headers[i]);
```